# devise change password not working (unknown attribute: current_password)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong but when a user tries to change their password on my app, it gives an error that current_password is an unknown attribute.

Here's my code:

```
def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
  registration_params = [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name]

  if params[:action] == 'update'
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:user_update) {
      |u| u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)
    }
  elsif params[:action] == 'create'
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {
      |u| u.permit(registration_params)
    }
  end
end

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:user_update)

    if account_update_params[:password].blank?
      account_update_params.delete("password")
      account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
      account_update_params.delete("current_password")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      sign_in @user, bypass: true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
```

what am i doing wrong here?  what should I be doing with current_password to check it is correct before saving their new password correctly?

EDIT:stack trace

```
activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:47:in `rescue in _assign_attribute'
activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `_assign_attribute'
activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:29:in `block in assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `each'
activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `assign_attributes'
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error? Can you share the error stacktrace.

Comment: getting the error on the line: @user.update_atributes(account_update_params).

Answer (score 12):

Instead of calling `@user.update_attributes(account_update_params)` which blows up because `current_password` isn't a field in the database (at least not in the default schema), try calling `update_resource(@user, account_update_params)` which is provided by Devise::RegistrationsController which you're inheriting from.  This in turn calls resource.update_with_password(params) which is provided by devise's `DatabaseAuthenticatable` module and checks the `current_password` before updating all the other params passed.

However, it looks like the standard DeviseController::RegistrationsController.update() would support what you want and more (e.g. handling if update needs a confirmation email); is there some reason why you need to override it?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue today with the following version of Ruby, Rails and Devise:

- ruby-2.4.0
- rails-5.1.4
- devise-4.3.0

Here is my solution:

#### Create your registration controller in `app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    # Require current password if user is trying to change password.
    return super if params["password"]&.present?

    # Allows user to update registration information without password.
    resource.update_without_password(params.except("current_password"))
  end
end
```

#### Tell Devise that you use your registrations controller defined in `app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb`.

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Devise 4,

When getting the **unknown attribute for 'current_password'**,
no need to play with the `devise_parameter_sanitizer`

Go into app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

Change

```
def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
end
```

By

```
def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_with_password(params)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

What to me it worked was:

Edit app/controllers/application_controller.rb

and add the following code

```
protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
end
```

Edit /app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb

and add the following code

```
protected

def update_resource(resource, params)
  resource.update_without_password(params)
end
```

and add the following route

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
```

Then, while trying to save changes without confirming the password, I did not return any problem.